# How to read the JSON file from HDFS path and use instead of MAP in Scala code

Tags: scala

```scala
val airportCodeToTimezoneMap = Map("MAA" -> "Asia/Kolkata" , "SHJ" -> "Asia/Dubai") 

val boardPoint =  "MAA" 

if( airportCodeToTimezoneMap.contains( boardPoint )) {
  println("Code  exists with value :"  + airportCodeToTimezoneMap(boardPoint))
} else {
  println("Code Not exist")
}

val tempValue = airportCodeToTimezoneMap(boardPoint) 

println(tempValue)
```

Here instead of
MAP i want to configure in JSON File in HDFS path and use it .

Say For E.G

```
    {
      "airportCode": "AAL",
      "zoneId": "Europe/Copenhagen"
    },
    {
      "airportCode": "AAM",
      "zoneId": "Africa/Johannesburg"
    }
```

Please tell me how to write it .

Comment: You can not directly use a file. You need something like a `Map` to be able to efficiently query the timezone for a given airport code. Your question should simply be - How to read json file to create Scala Map ? But the problem with this is that this is a pretty basic use case. What will you even do after you get this piece of code? Please learn basic Scala before jumping to writing complex applications.

Comment: This is pretty simple. Think of it setp by step. You need to know - 1 ) How to parse a json string in Scala to get a Json object, then build Map from that Json object ? - You can use any json library like Play Json, Circe, Gson, Jackson for this. 2 ) How to get String from File ? - You should be able to find this by simple google search. 3 ) How to get File from HDFS file path ? - Again, google search.